# Wholesaler uses Magento SOAP API v2 - does this mean I'm restricted to using Magento?

Tags: magento, shopify

I've recently got in contact with a wholesaler who stocks products matching my site.

They offer an API to process orders, and automatically check their stock - which is appealing to me as it would save me time.

They have provided me PHP code, but the references are to Magentos SOAP API v2.

Is it possible to use Shopify instead of Magento, or am I stuck using Magento for my site?

Thanks for your time

Comment: No, they must have Magento. You can use anything.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the reply, good to know as I would prefer Shopify as I'm new to E-commerce. Thanks for your time!